# How to embed .css files into jar and attach via @CssImport

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'd like to create some vaadin components in a jar separate from my application. Can I use the @CssImport annotation to attach styles to these components?

Comment: Assuming, that you have tried and it did not work: Please add the code
you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors, stacktraces, logs, ...)
so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work when setting them according to the [Resource Cheat Sheet](https://vaadin.com/docs/v20/flow/advanced/loading-resources#resource-cheat-sheet) ([v14 documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-ways-of-importing#resource-cheat-sheet))

The directory for the css files should be under `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/` in the .jar project.

Comment: The section to look at from the documentation is `Table 3. Add-ons` which is for components packaged as an add-on .jar to be used in other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's what I had been looking for.